# Increment index of reference

Tags: java, arrays

I've got an integer that refers to a value stored in an array. How can i increment the index it refers to?

```
int[] pos={0,1,2};
int thisPos=pos[1];
thisPos=pos[++]; //-> thisPos=pos[2];
```

Comment: It doesn't refer to any index. `thisPos` is a container for an `int` value. That's all.

Comment: the variable `thisPos` does not refer to any index. it simply contains a value that happens to be the same value stored in `pos[1]`. you cannot increment it to the next array element. the best you could do would be store the position, increment that position, and then index into that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the index separately:

```
int index = 1;
int thisPos = pos[index];
index++;
thisPos = pos[index];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
pos[2]
```

If you wanted to keep track of a position, then you'll want a variable to hold it:

```
int i = 1;
thisPos = pos[i];
i = i+1;
thisPos = pos[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to scan the array to find that value (and hope that the value is UNIQUE within the array) and get its index, then increment that index. e.g.

```
curPos = find_index_for_value(pos[1]); // index = 1
curPos = curPos + 1;
thisPos = pos[curPos];
```

But like I said, you have to be sure there's no duplicate values in the array. e.g. if the array was

```
{0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,5}
 a b c d e f g h i j
```

and `curPos` was `2` - then **WHICH** of the two `2` values are you at? `c` or `h`?

Comment: I feel like you are misunderstanding the question. At least, this is not my impression of what OP wants.

Comment: how so? `thisPos` has a value from the array, and OP wants to move to the next array entry AFTER that value.